# Instantiating Custom Object with Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

Currently whenever I want to save a custom object called `List` I use

(Core Date + [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord))

`List *list = [List MR_createInContext:_managedObjectContext];`

Now I'm wondering whether I could instantiate a List item like this

```
List *localList = [[List alloc] init];
// set some properties
localList.name = @"foobar";

List *newList = [List MR_createInContext:_managedObjectContext];
newList = locaList
```

Will this cause any problems with Core Data/memory issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for a couple of reasons:

1. You can't use `init` with managed objects. The designated initializer is `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`. There's also a convenience constructor on `NSEntityDescription` called `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:`. If you don't use one of those, you'll have problems.
2. When you assign `newList = localList`, you throw away the previous object in `localList` with all of its data. All that's left after this point is the one you originally assigned to `newList`. Your assignment to `localList.name`, for example, disappears with the `localList` object.

Comment: `List` is the OP's class -- we don't know what it's `init` method might do.

Answer (score -2):

Since you've defined `List` it's hard to say whether you're creating a `List` instance correctly in both cases. At the very least your code leaks the second `List` that you create, and it seems unlikely that that code does what you think it does.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
List *localList = [[List alloc] init];
// set some properties
localList.name = @"foobar";

List *newList = localList;
```

Comment: Does it make sense to just read and right my properties from Core Data each time? I just feel like that's memory expensive, no?

Comment: if this won't work, could you shed some light on using this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801648/destroying-an-object-in-core-data-before-its-saved