# Destroying an object in Core Data before it's saved

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

If I create a new Custom Object in Core Date (using Magical Record) like so

```
List *list = [List MR_createInContext:_managedObjectContext];
```

And then I perform various actions on it, such as setting its name

```
list.name = @"Foobar List";
```

But then the user decides to cancel the creation of this list, do I need to delete? As in, is this list already in memory even though I haven't saved the local context with `[localContext MR_save];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the object in the managed object context, it will get saved the next time you save changes. If you don't want to save it, you'll have to delete it.

Comment: Cool, thanks Tom. Also, would you mind taking a quick look at another question I had very much related to this? Is doing whta you mentioned above (creating the object in a managedcontext and then deleting it if it's not used) best pratice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801775/creating-a-instance-variable-using-core-data-and-magical-record